# Long pause between USB accesses on virtual COM port on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, com-port

I have 2 PCs here in my company with Windows 10 installed. I'm using a Perl program to access hardware via a virtual COM port (created by an FTDI232H chip and the respective driver).

On one PC (my laptop), if I do back-to-back accesses, they have a pause of some 2..5ms inbetween. On the other PC (a tower), when I do exactly the same with the same program and hardware, I get pauses of 50..80ms between back-to-back accesses.

Can anyone think of how I can speed up the slow PC?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: After running for over an hour at the slow speed, the slow PC suddenly put up steam and is now running at the same speed as the other PC. I have no explanation for that. Both PCs had been up and running for many hours.

Comment: After running for another hour on high speed, the PC got tired and is running now on slow speed again. This is mysterious...